# C program gives strange results

Tags: c

I just started programming and came up with a program to count the number of characters in an input.

The code is as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    char sentence[20];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", sentence);

    while ( sentence[number] != '\n' )
    {
        counter += 1;
        number += 1;
    }

    printf("no. of characters in sentence you just typed: %d", counter);

    return 1;    
}
```

This program has a strange behavior that I cannot understand. It compiles without error but no matter how many characters I type or what character is entered, it shows the no. of characters as 817.

I am curious as to why 817? It's really weird. Also please enlighten me on how I can improve my code since it did not perform as expected.

Comment: If you had stepped through with your debugger, you would have found the problem easily.

Comment: No attempt at debugging.  Down and close vote.  Next............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf reads input till `\n` but not including it So :

```
while ( sentence[number] != '\n' ) // always true for legal array bound
```

will lead to illegal memory access, causing undefined behavior. If you do wish to read the string including the [[ white-space ]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm) characters, use [[ fgets ]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

If you wish to count the number of characters, change the `while` loop to

```
while ( sentence[number] != '\0' )
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` with the argument `"%s"` reads one word, up to the first space or tab or newline, and will not include any `\n` character in the input. Your loop will never end. Or, more accurately, it will give what the C standard calls "undefined behaviour". In practice, it means that it will keep looping until it either finds a newline somewhere in memory (perhaps 817 places from the start!), or reaches the end of allocated memory and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) the function `scanf` does not read white space.

Perhaps [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) would be a better choice along with changing the while loop to

```
while (sentence[number] != 0 && sentence[number] != '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line :

```
while ( sentence[number] != '\n' )
```

to

```
while ( sentence[number] != '\0' )
```

and `return 0` at the end

Comment: Worth mentioning why the op should change this :-)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a better version of code to count the number of characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    double c;
    for(n=0; getchar() != EOF; ++n);
    printf("%.0f\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Where is the string stored? What is double c?

Comment: double is a data type like int, I have used it if the length of the input string is very long. The String is not stored here it just counts the number of characters from the input.

Comment: You should not be storing integer values in a `double`. Double's lose accuracy if it get's too high. An `int` would easily suffice, it could count up to 2GB (or 4 if you used unsigned) of values, which the user really wouldn't be entering. If you needed more than that, you'd use a `long long` which could store 8 Exabytes, far beyond what would ever be expected). You are also then incrementing `n` which is never defined, you've thrown away all the characters recieved and this loop won't end until the input stream is closed, rather than the user pressing enter.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!